# A convergence problem related to Kolmogorov's Three Series Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $\{X_n:n\geqslant1\}$ is sequence of independent random variables, satisfying that $\mathbb E|X_n|<\infty$ and $\mathbb EX_n=0$ for all $n\geqslant1$. If $\mathbb E\sup_n|X_n|<\infty$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ converges almost surely, prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb E\frac{X_n^2}{1+|X_n|}<\infty.$$

My first thought is to apply Kolmogorov's Three Series Theorem to obtain that for any $C>0$ we have the following:

(1) $\sum_{n\geqslant1}\mathbb P(|X_n|>C)<\infty$;

(2)$\sum_{n\geqslant1}\mathbb EX_nI_{(|X_n|\leqslant C)}$ converges;

(3)$\sum_{n\geqslant1}Var(X_nI_{(|X_n|\leqslant1)})=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\left[\mathbb EX_n^2I_{(|X_n|\leqslant C)}-(\mathbb EX_nI_{(|X_n|\leqslant C)})^2\right]<\infty$.

We usually take $C=1$. I am trying to consider  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb E\frac{X_n^2}{1+|X_n|}I_{(|X_n|\leqslant1)}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb E\frac{X_n^2}{1+|X_n|}I_{(|X_n|>1)}$ separately. I note that $$\mathbb E\frac{X_n^2}{1+|X_n|}I_{(|X_n|\leqslant1)}\leqslant\mathbb EX_n^2I_{(|X_n|\leqslant1)}\leqslant2\mathbb E\frac{X_n^2}{1+|X_n|}I_{(|X_n|\leqslant1)}.$$
It means that I have to show $\sum_{n\geqslant1}EX_n^2I_{(|X_n|\leqslant1)}<\infty$. This is my first problem.

As for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb E\frac{X_n^2}{1+|X_n|}I_{(|X_n|>1)}$, I want to find a upper bound of form $C_1\mathbb E\sup_n|X_n|$. This is my second problem.

By the way, $\mathbb E\sup_n|X_n|<\infty$ could imply the uniform integrability of $\{X_n\}$, and $\mathbb EX_n=0$ could imply $\mathbb |EX_nI_{(|X_n|\leqslant1)}|=|EX_nI_{(|X_n|>1)}|$.

Please feel free to discuss it. :)